# The value of the variable "m" is not getting updated when i am trying to print the string which is declared outside the loop

Tags: java, arrays, string, for-loop

This is the code I'm trying to execute:

```
class test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    int num = 5;
    var i = 0;
    int m = 0;
    String[] m_id = {"1","2","3","4","5"};
    String sample = "Checking if this works" +" " +m_id[m];
    
    for (i=0; i<num; i++) 
    {
        m=m+1;
        System.out.println(sample);
    }
  }
}
```

I am getting the output as:

Checking if this works 1
Checking if this works 1
Checking if this works 1
Checking if this works 1
Checking if this works 1

Instead i need :

Checking if this works 1
Checking if this works 2
Checking if this works 3
Checking if this works 4
Checking if this works 5

Comment: Additionally update _sample_ from within the loop.

Comment: How to update? @Reilas

Comment: There is no link between `String sample = "Checking if this works" +" " +m_id[m];` and subsequent changes to the value of `m`.

Comment: The problem seems to indicate a misunderstanding of the nature of ['assignment'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_(computer_science)) in imperative programming.

Answer (score 2):

Everything is fine with the variable `m`. The problem is that your string variable `sample` is not only declared, but also assigned outside the loop and never updated. Why do you expect it to change it's value? It always has the value that was assigned to it: "Checking if this works 1", because `m` was 0 at the moment of assignment and the value that you got from the array was "1".

In order to get the desired behaviour you should change your code in the following way:

```
String sample = "";

for (i = 0; i < num; i++) {
    sample = "Checking if this works" + " " + m_id[m]; // update the value
    System.out.println(sample);
    m = m + 1;
}
```

You also can do it like that:

```
String pattern = "Checking if this works %s";

for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
    System.out.println(String.format(pattern, m_id[m]));
    m = m + 1;
}
```

Comment: This is fine but is there any way to just update the string which is declared outside the loop before the iteration? Because i need multiple methods to access it.

Comment: @SAMSONJACK consider updating your question with more details of what you really want. "just update the string which is declared outside the loop before the iteration" - that is exactly what I'm doing in the code. Maybe you mean something else when you say "update the string" :)

Comment: @SAMSONJACK checkout my updated code, I have a blind guess, maybe that's what you want :)

Comment: This sounds like an [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info).  Please show your use case as to why you need to do this.

Comment: There is no spooky action at a distance.

Comment: Let me make it clear: I have multiple if else statements and a for loop inside it, everytime i run a for loop the value in the string should be updated. I don't have to declare the string in every loop. so i have commonly created the string outside the loop and expecting it to change values. Is there any possible ways or i am missing something here

Comment: @SAMSONJACK but isn't it exactly what the code in my answer is doing? The string is created outside the loop and updated inside it.

Comment: Thanks @AndrejIstomin, That works and that is what i was searching for.

Comment: @SAMSONJACK I'm glad it helped you :) Consider marking my answer as accepted :)

Answer (score 0):

Replace this section :

```
String sample = "Checking if this works" +" " +m_id[m];    
for (i=0; i<num; i++) 
{
    m=m+1;
    System.out.println(sample);
}
```

by this :

```
String sample = "Checking if this works" +" "; 
for (i=0; i<num; i++) 
{
    System.out.println(sample+m_id[m]);
    m=m+1;
   
}
```